# Limit the Number of Column based Headers

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This code pulls data from the entire sheet, can we limit it based on the number of headers inserted in the table?

```
<table class="table">

  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>EMPLOYEE</th>
      <th>IN-TIME</th>
      <th>OUT-TIME</th>
      <th>DURATION</th>
      <th>STATUS</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <? var data = getData(); ?>

  <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>

  <tr>
    <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
    <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
    <? } ?>
  </tr>
  <? } ?>
</table>
```

Get data code

```
  function getData() {
      return SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('15Sb-g71H6-7PPey3aQROo-oCx_ULKQq2a5')
      .getSheetByName("TODAY")
      .getDataRange()
      .getDisplayValues();
    }
```

Comment: In your situation, I thought that to modify the script of `getData()` might be suitable. So can you provide the script of `getData()`?

Comment: @Tanaike I've edited with get data code

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. In your case, the header row is the 1st row? And, the values of header are the same with `<th>EMPLOYEE</th><th>IN-TIME</th><th>OUT-TIME</th><th>DURATION</th><th>STATUS</th>`? Or, if the values of header are not the same with the header values of sheet, you want to retrieve 5 columns of A to E?

Comment: @Tanaike That's correct. I'want to retrieve column A to E. (I have to put the headers one by one because I don't know the code that should come in <thead> "code" </<thead>

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

## Question 1:

I believe your goal as follows.

- Header row of the Spreadsheet is the 1st row.
- The header values of the Spreadsheet are not the same with `<th>EMPLOYEE</th><th>IN-TIME</th><th>OUT-TIME</th><th>DURATION</th><th>STATUS</th>`. So you want to retrieve 5 columns of A to E.

#### Modification points:

- I thought that to modify the script of `getData()` might be suitable for achieving your goal.
- For the script of `getData()`, the values are retrieved using `getRange`. For this, the number of headers is declared.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function getData() {
  const headerColumns = 5;  // In your case, the number of header columns is 5.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('15Sb-g71H6-7PPey3aQROo-oCx_ULKQq2a5').getSheetByName("TODAY");
  const values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, headerColumns).getDisplayValues();
  return values;
}
```

#### Reference:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

## Question 2:

I believe your goal as follows.

- Header row of the Spreadsheet is the 1st row.
- You want to retrieve 5 columns of A to E by giving the number of columns.
- You want to also put the values of header row to the HTML template.

#### Modified script:

In this case, both HTML and Google Apps Script are required to be modified as follows.

HTML side:

```
<table class="table">
  <? var [header, ...data] = getData(); ?>
  <thead class="thead-dark"><tr>
  <? for (var j = 0; j < header.length; j++) { ?>
    <th><?= header[j] ?></th>
  <? } ?>
  </tr></thead>

  <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
  <tr>
    <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
    <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
    <? } ?>
  </tr>
  <? } ?>
</table>
```

Google Apps Script side:

```
function getData() {
  const headerColumns = 5;  // In your case, the number of header columns is 5.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('15Sb-g71H6-7PPey3aQROo-oCx_ULKQq2a5').getSheetByName("TODAY");
  const values = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), headerColumns).getDisplayValues();
  console.log(values)
  return values;
}
```

Comment: This works, Thank you :) Can you tell  me if I want to pull the headers name into <thead> </thead> than writing it manually, what would it be?

Comment: @Muhammed Aadhil Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I added one more sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: That worked like charm :) Thank you very much, it's going to help me a lot. :)